# how i can set this src value using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var fileref = document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?
                            q="+buildString+"&callback=TweetTick&rpp=50");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

Here buildString value is

```
from:@one+OR+from:null+OR+from:@two+OR+from:null+OR+from:@three+OR+
from:null+OR+from:null+OR+from:@four+OR+from:null+OR+from:@five+OR+
from:null+OR+from:@six+OR+from:null+OR+from:@seven+OR+from:null+OR+
from:@eight
```

Here when i used `buildString` value( i.e what i specified ) to set the value for src it is working properly for me.

But if i set `buildString` directly it is giving exception for me.

```
  SyntaxError: illegal character

TweetTick(�
```

If my question is not clear i will explain more detail.

Please help me.Thanks in advance..

Comment: From where you are getting `buildString` variable ?

Comment: from a loop that exist just before the code what i posted

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: sorry it is difficult for me to create

Comment: Try `console.log(buildString)` and see if it's correct ?

Comment: but when i compare those 2 values i am getting true

Comment: @MohammadAdil it is giving the same thing

Comment: What did it log? if you console.log(buildString) what do you see in the console. You can use Firefox with firebug plugin or chrome and press F12 to see the developer tools

Comment: i see .It is coming as same

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var source = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q="+buildString+"&callback=TweetTick&rpp=50";
fileref.setAttribute("src",encodeURI(source));
```

Comment: do you mean `fileref.setAttribute("src",source);` ??

Comment: what is the reason for this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Seems like API v1 search has stopped working, you should upgrade to API v1.1 which now require authentificated user. Even direct link to API search seems still to work, i can no more access it using ajax json request.

See (not clear) annoucement here: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/planning-for-api-v1-retirement